# How to Set Font Kerning property in c#

Tags: c#, fonts, kerning

How to set the Font property Kerning and Use Context Properties in C# . It is possible to set in Word
[image]

So I'm trying to set the font property and write it to pdf . So everytime I write it gives extra space . If I'm able to set the kerning property then it will solve the problem. If I write to html using CSS and set kerning property to 1 then the it is rendered perfectly .This is easy to do in css but how to set this in C#

Comment: Be a bit more specific here. Do you want to change that in c# for your editor like in word. Do you want it to change in c# for your own c# program like in word. Or do you want to change word settings via c#. Or something else?

Comment: So I'm trying to set the font property and write it to pdf  . So everytime I write it gives extra space . If I'm able to set the kerning property then it will solve the problem. If I write to html using CSS and set kerning property to 1 then the it is rendered perfectly . I have in house tool for rendering pdf so if I can set this property it would solve